# ASP.NET, Automatically make button click from page load

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to make a button click event run from the page load?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

if your button has runat="server" you can access it from codebehind.
you could insert a click action on the button in the page_load event. but it's better to create a function with all actions to call both from button click and page_load.

```html
<asp:Button id="btn1">Click here</asp:Button>
```

```html
void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
{
     doThis();
}

void btn1_click()
{
     doThis();
}

void doThis()
{
     //click actions
}
```

Another way to do it is by javascript. find the button when document is ready and fire the click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the logic behind the button click event in a function and call that function from the page load.

Comment: Why not use JQuery if you need to actually perform a click?